# home page jumps to iframe on load

Tags: html, iframe

I'm having a weird issue with an iframe on one of my sites. I set the iframe src to a specific part of another page like so:

```
<iframe src="blog#content"></iframe>
```

When the page(not the iframe) is refreshed from the top, the page jumps back to where the iframe is(bottom of page).

It works fine when `src="blog"` instead of `src="blog#content`

**What's going on here?**

Comment: Could you throw us up a JSBin or Codepen?

Comment: this is the site http://gabesbikeshopla.com

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error. Could you edit your question above to include a very specific, step-by-step description of the observed versus desired behavior, please?

Comment: Oops I removed `#content` from the src cause I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: I'm still not able to reproduce the error. Again, please describe exactly the steps to reproduce, the observed behavior, and the desired behavior.

Comment: @janaspage I changed the src to blog#content. When u land on the page, it jumps down to the blog area instead of it focusing on the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work.

You will have to make a new html file.

Put this in that:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("#div1").load("blog #content");
   });
</script>
```

Now save that html file, and put iframe as that file.

You don't really need an iframe though, you can just put that code directly to the place where you want it to appear.

Comment: this gives me some crazy stuff. nice try tho

Comment: This works, for the 'crazy stuff' you will need to put links to your css and javascript files which are available at your 'blog' if they are not on file you will have to copy paste them from there. That will get you the design and layout.